# How to increment value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, increment

I'm a little new to Postgres. I want to take a value (which is an integer) in a field in a Postgres table and increment it by one. For example, if the table 'totals' had 2 columns, 'name' and 'total', and Bill had a total of 203, what would be the SQL statement I'd use in order to move Bill's total to 204?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

```
UPDATE totals 
   SET total = total + 1
WHERE name = 'bill';
```

If you want to make sure the current value is indeed 203 (and not accidently increase it again) you can also add another condition:

```
UPDATE totals 
   SET total = total + 1
WHERE name = 'bill'
  AND total = 203;
```

Comment: I was trying to increment **non-integer** datatype and getting:`ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying + integer
LINE 2:         SET total = total + 1`

Solved by casting the value as integer like this `SET total = total::int + 1`

Comment: @Stew-au: Do ***not*** store numbers in varchar columns. That will give you trouble in the long run. Use an integer (or bigint or whatever is suitable) but do not use a character datatype.

Comment: Is this statement atomic or would I need pessimistic lock the table for writes first? (My fear is that in between of assigning total and the fetching of total for total + 1 some writing has been done to the table.)

Comment: A single statement is always atomic in a relational database. However running the update will not prevent others from _reading_ the old values until your transaction is committed

Comment: And how it'll be for upsert? Cauz if I try to use `total = total + EXCLUDED.total` it show error: **ERROR:  column reference "total" is ambiguous at character XYZ**.

Comment: How can I insert it if the key is not exist?

Comment: For upsert see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161127/column-reference-is-ambiguous-when-upserting-element-into-table