# Updating and inserting a value in a database, locking its table and avoid multiple connection while working on the SELECT from php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, locking

I need to update and/or insert in a Postgres DB, a String value with letters and numbers, which must be incremented of +1 (through php strings functions) everytime there is an `UPDATE`.

I need to `LOCK` this table, in order for the php to complete its flow in inserting or updating it avoiding others that open the page to receive the same result of the `SELECT`.

The second arrived, would wait for the first to finish.

The second arrived, will ALWAYS make an `UPDATE`.
This update could generate a FILENAME0023, if there were 22 updates after the first insertion.

There could be more connections at the same time, I need to reserve the first result of the `SELECT` for the first one who connected to this php page.

The flow would be:

```
LOCK
    SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 'FILENAME0001';

    IF NOT EXIST { INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ($my_column); }
    ELSE { UPDATE table SET column = '$my_new_column' WHERE column = '$my_column'; }
UNLOCK
```

The variable `$my_new_column` is a `SUBSTR` php function that would cut the number part of the string and will then be incremented of +1.

This link is helping me a lot: [THIS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html).
But it does not contain everything.

I also tried working with stored procedure: [LINK](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php)
But I should work on the php when it is an update because I cannot increment a DB value like shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233298/increment-a-value-in-postgres), because I do not have a `INT` but a string and I can not change this

Anyone who can help me?
I'd like to share my code, but believe me I'd rather start fresh, all the codes I tried are leading to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use

```
`INSERT ON ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
```

[Here link for more example about it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I am in version 9.4 of postgre (not mysql) and do not have this command. I might create a function for that, but the value must be increased from PHP because is a string that contains numbers. Besides, updating is quite simple, it is the locking that is giving me issue in developing it

Comment: this is mysql syntax not postgresql